# Way to convert user account on Windows 10 from on-prem AD to AzureAD?

Tags: active-directory, entra-id

Many employees are now remote that haven't been in the past. We would like them to start using an AzureAD logon for their laptops instead of user tied to our office's Active Directory system. My understand is that if they just setup a new user tied to Azure then they would have to reinstall everything. Is there anyway to avoid that and convert a user mostly seamlessly?

Comment: Why don't you just utilize a VPN that places the remote worker on the internal network with the DCs?

Comment: When I last looked into this years ago there was not a way to do it with our VPN but we have since changed our system. I just found a write up about how to achieve it with FortiClient which is our current VPN system. Will discuss with others to see if this will be a satisfactory approach for now. In the long run though, we are a small group and believe having everyone on a consistent auth system that does not require VPN would be more ideal. Some newer employees have never had VPN and have no need for anything on our office network.

Answer (score 0):

They shouldn't need to reinstall applications, but you will probably need to copy their on premises AD user account profile to their Azure AD user account profile. There are a number of vendors who have solutions for this. Laplink being one of them.

But, as WakeDemons3 asked, wouldn't it be better and less disruptive to have them connect to the on premises AD via a VPN? What are you trying to achieve by joining these computers to Azure AD?